# unable to execute command: Bus error: 10 IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, runtime, clang

I have one fuzzy problem in my Xcode . After Re-install my **X-Code Version 4.3.2 (4E2002)** , When i run any of my code it shows below error message .

Error :

Some Text Like :

```
Ld /Users/vivek/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MapDirectionsViewExample-gbobmtqliuwpjbbhsaxeqrqgzyax/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MapDirectionsViewExample.app/MapDirectionsViewExample normal i386
    cd /Users/vivek/Desktop/MapDirectionViewController-master/Example
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -L/Users/vivek/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MapDirectionsViewExample-gbobmtqliuwpjbbhsaxeqrqgzyax/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/vivek/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MapDirectionsViewExample-gbobmtqliuwpjbbhsaxeqrqgzyax/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/vivek/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MapDirectionsViewExample-gbobmtqliuwpjbbhsaxeqrqgzyax/Build/Intermediates/MapDirectionsViewExample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MapDirectionsViewExample.build/Objects-normal/i386/MapDirectionsViewExample.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40200 -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -lz -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreLocation -framework MapKit -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/vivek/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MapDirectionsViewExample-gbobmtqliuwpjbbhsaxeqrqgzyax/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MapDirectionsViewExample.app/MapDirectionsViewExample
```

**AND ERROR MESSAGE LIKE ,**

> clang: error: unable to execute command: Bus error: 10 clang: error:
>   linker command failed due to signal 2 (use -v to see invocation)
>   clang: note: diagnostic msg: Please submit a bug report to
>   http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include command line
>   arguments and all diagnostic information. clang: note: diagnostic msg:
>   Error generating preprocessed source(s) - no preprocessable inputs.

What I need to do I am not getting .

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance .

image :

[image]

Comment: Did you try to remove your all projects Derived data folders, in your case it'll here: `/Users/vivek/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`. remove all project's folder [No worries, its safe] and do a `Product > Clean` your projects from Xcode menu.

Comment: no I dint try that @AdilSoomro . Let me try that .. Someone told its garbage collection problem in xcode 4.3 . And I cant upgrade xcode so I need some proper solution on this . And one more thing that I have recently formatted my macbook so there is no data on my machin ..